# How do you ensure all child elements of an angular component are a specific type?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have this use case I am trying to implement in Angular — A header component that can be placed on a page that has a container for small icon buttons. Something like this:

[image: Heading with Icon Buttons]

Each instance of the header can have different icon buttons transcluded in it. It must only contain these kinds of buttons and the buttons cannot exist unless contained within the header. Basically this:

```html
<my-header title="Heading Text">
  <my-header-button icon-class="save" (clicked)="doSave()"></my-header-button>
  <my-header-button icon-class="mail" (clicked)="doMail()"></my-header-button>
  <my-header-button icon-class="flag" (clicked)="doFlag()"></my-header-button>
</my-header>
```

The **parent component** is designed like this:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-header',
  template: `
      <header>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div><ng-content></ng-content></div>
      </header>
    `
})

export class HeaderComponent {
  @Input() title = '';
}
```

The **child component** is implemented like this:

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-header-button',
    template: `
      <a (click)="onClick($event)"><i class="{{icon-class}}"</a>
    `,
})

export class HeaderButtonComponent {
    constructor(parent: HeaderComponent) { }
    @Input() public iconClass: string = '';
    @Output() public clicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    private onClick(button): void {
        this.clicked.emit(button);
    }
}
```

I am able to ensure that the `my-header-button` cannot be used outside of the parent by referencing the parent type in the constructor (`constructor(parent: HeaderComponent) { }`. My two questions:

**How do you ensure all child elements of the `my-header` element are only `my-header-button` elements?**

**Also, how do I make sure that each `my-header-button` can take a router link (`[routerLink]="['/some-link']`)?**

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, trying out @ViewChild might be a solution

Try `@ViewChild(HeaderButtonComponent) appButton: HeaderButtonComponent;`
https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

For the second question, assign something unique for example an id to header buttons and give the path 
`routerLink = "/some-link/{{button.id}}"`

further use params and ActivatedRoute module to get id from the url. For further details checkout the docs
https://angular.io/guide/router